# importing wrong module in script

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to import this module, exactly as per the documentation

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
```

I get the below error. It's trying to import the requests module, not pytrends.request

How can I get around this?

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry'; 'requests.packages.urllib3.util' is not a package
```

Comment: I assume you installed with `pip install pytrends`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

First,

```
pip install requests lxml pandas
```

Also, make sure that you have installed `pytrends` as the comment suggests.

```
pip install pytrends
```

Also, make sure there no conflicts between conda and your default ecosystem.